# How to define a Python dictionary type hint with specific key-value type relationships

Tags: python, dictionary, typing

Is this possible to tell python I have a `dict` which either has a `Fruit` key with `int` value type or `Car` key that has a `str` type value assigned?

```py
Fruit = NewType("fruit", int)
Car = NewType("car", str)

# NewDictType = Dict[Union[Fruit, Car], Union[int, str]]
NewDictType = Union[Dict[Fruit, int], Dict[Car,  str]]

test:NewDictType = dict()
number: int = test[Fruit(0)]
# Diagnostics:
# 1. Argument of type "fruit" cannot be assigned to parameter "__key" of type "car" in function "__getitem__"
     "fruit" is incompatible with "car"
# 2. Expression of type "int | str" cannot be assigned to declared type "int"
     Type "int | str" cannot be assigned to type "int"
       "str" is incompatible with "int"
```

Answer (score 0):

`test`, as a *union* of two `dict` types, can only be used with operations that apply to *either*. You *can* do the following:

```
test: NewDictType = {Fruit(0): 3}
```

because `{Fruit(0): 3}` has a type that's a subtype of `NewDictType`. However, the indexing still fails:

```
number = test[Fruit(0)]
```

`Fruit(0)` is not a valid key for a dict of type `Dict[Car, str]`, and so it's not a valid key for a dict of type `NewDictType` either.

Basically, you need to be specific about the type of `test` if you actually want to *use* `test` in any meaningful way.